# neo4j 3.4 keeps reloading web page on Safari

Tags: neo4j, reloading

Title says it all.

Message I see: "This webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred"

this hasn't been the case with the previous release 3.x releases but it's driving me nuts because every time I want to go back and check a previous command and results the page has reloaded and I have to start all over....

This is happening on macOS High Sierra

Any suggestions to resolve this other than change browser ...

-m

Comment: We've noted this one as well. The Neo4j browser team is aware of this.

Comment: In the meantime, check out this link. (https://appletoolbox.com/2015/10/a-problem-occurred-with-this-webpage-so-it-was-reloaded-fix/). Something on there might work for you. (It's a very generic Safari error, so sadly, there are a lot of things that could be the cause, but worth a shot)

Comment: Could you provide a dataset and queries where this happens consistently?

Comment: @OskarHane No data set needed, no action needed, except to bring up the browser in Safari and wait (using Sierra for me, unsure if this persists in High Sierra). While you could load the movies dataset, I am unsure if the presence of data accelerates the issue. Left alone, the web page crashes and reloads. Especially annoying when working on a query or referencing past queries and results in the browser.

Comment: any updates on this issue @neo4j ???